# Fill up pandas dataframes with constant value for each dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large number of dataframes that look like this:

```
     state1 state2  count
0      A       B      2
1      A       B      16
2      A       B      4
```

Each df has different values for state1 and state2 (however, within each df, values for state1 and state2 are identical for each row), and the number of rows ranges from 1-5.
For each df, I'd like to fill up the number of rows to a total of 5, with the additional rows each having a count of 0. For the above example, this would look like this:

```
     state1 state2  count
0      A       B      2
1      A       B      16
2      A       B      4
3      A       B      0
4      A       B      0
```

This is probably trivial, but what's the best (most efficient) way of doing this for lots of dataframes? I'd like to avoid looping over rows, if possible. Many thanks!

Comment: ``df.reindex(range(5)).fillna({'count':0}, downcast='infer').ffill()`` ? feels like a dupe; however, I cant find the duplicate

Answer (score 0):

One option is to reindex with a range, fill the count column with 0, and finally forward fill the remaining columns:

```py
df.reindex(range(5)).fillna({'count':0}, downcast='infer').ffill() 

  state1 state2  count
0      A      B      2
1      A      B     16
2      A      B      4
3      A      B      0
4      A      B      0
```

Comment: Why `downcast='infer'`?

Comment: downcast to the lowest acceptable data type, which so happens to be an int ( could be an int8, int16, ... whatever the minimum acceptable data type can be)

Comment: perfect, thanks!